# Read the first two children table rows for every parent table that have children or connected tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I wanna read the first two children for every parent that have children

Like i have two tables

Parent Table

- John
- Ketty
- James

Childs Table

| Child | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| Maria | John |
| Donald | John |
| Rice | James |
| Evan | John |

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM childs WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM parent WHERE childs.parent = parent.parent) LIMIT 2
```